# Why can't I seem to get the SimpleFTPSample code to work for me?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ftp

I've been trying and trying to get Apples SimpleFTPSample to work for me, but I just can't.  Here's the code I've been using:

```
BOOL                    success;
CFWriteStreamRef        ftpStream;

NSLog(@"Hello");
// assert(self.networkStream == nil);      // don't tap send twice in a row!
// assert(self.fileStream == nil);         // ditto

// First get and check the URL.

url = [NSURL URLWithString:@hostname];
success = (url != nil);
NSLog(@"After first success");
if (success) {
    NSLog(@"In the success if");
    // Add the last part of the file name to the end of the URL to form the final 
    // URL that we're going to put to.
    if(fileName) NSLog(@"Filename.");
    if(url) NSLog(@"url");
    url = [NSMakeCollectable(
                             CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, (CFURLRef) url,
                                                                   //(CFStringRef) [fileName lastPathComponent], 
                                                                   (CFStringRef)pngPath,
                                                                   false)
                             ) autorelease];
    [url retain];
    NSLog(@"After url=");
    success = (url != nil);
    assert(success);
    NSLog(@"End of success if");
}
// If the URL is bogus, let the user know.  Otherwise kick off the connection.

if ( ! success) {
    NSLog(@"Invalid URL");
} else {

    // Open a stream for the file we're going to send.  We do not open this stream; 
    // NSURLConnection will do it for us.

    self.fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:pngPath];
    assert(self.fileStream != nil);

    [self.fileStream open];

    // Open a CFFTPStream for the URL.

    ftpStream = CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (CFURLRef) url);
    if(!ftpStream) NSLog(@"ftpStream is null");
    assert(ftpStream != NULL);

    self.networkStream = (NSOutputStream *) ftpStream;


#pragma unused (success) //Adding this to appease the static analyzer.
    success = [self.networkStream setProperty:@"JEFF" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
    assert(success);
    success = [self.networkStream setProperty:@"jeffrack" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];
    assert(success);


    self.networkStream.delegate = self;
    [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.networkStream open];

    // Have to release ftpStream to balance out the create.  self.networkStream 
    // has retained this for our persistent use.

    CFRelease(ftpStream);

    // Tell the UI we're sending.

    [self _sendDidStart];
}
```

}

In this example, hostname is the IP address for the FTP server.  The problem I keep getting is that at my `NSLog(@"After url=")` url keeps being null and I can't figure out why it keeps being created as null.  Also, pngPath is the NSString that where the image I'm trying to upload is located. Does anybody know a simple way of editing their simple sample that works, because I've been at this for a couple of weeks and just can't get it to work.

Also, I can't find anything on their API to make it send in passive mode, does anybody know how I could make that work also?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Operations with NSString are problematic for scheme protocol ("ftp://" for instance), because as soon as you modify your NSString, it will replace any sequence of "/" characters by a unique "/".

In fact, it becomes problematic with "/" when you use any "pathComponent" or "path" function from NSString class, that will return not a NSString but a NSPathStore2 Class object. That's this class (NSPathStore2) that make funky things with "/".

Then, when you try to use it to make a NSURL, it will fail because the start of the adress becomes "ftp:/myhost/mypath/myfile.ext". One "/" is missing after "ftp:/".

To avoid this problem, here's what I did quickly :

```
NSString *myPath = [[@"ftp:%2F%2FmyFtpDomain/myPath" 
                                 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFilename.ext"]
stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I escaped the "/" at the creation of the adress by its escaped code %2F, and finally unescaped them.

For the passive mode, use the 'kCFStreamPropertyFTPUsePassiveMode' property of your NSStream :

```
[_outputStream setProperty:( _passiveMode ? (id)kCFBooleanTrue : (id)kCFBooleanFalse ) forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUsePassiveMode]
```